# assets:precompile fails with unknown variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my working dev system to another machine using capistrano, so I don't know where the problem lies - with dev, production or me ;)

I am trying to precompile the assets, but get this error :

bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

rake aborted!
Undefined variable: "$grayLight".
  (in /opt/data/rails/project/releases/20121002101450/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)

I am using twitter-bootstrap

I honestly have been reading up on anything that I can find, but cannot get this thing to work. Would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: where do you have this error? on your dev machine? what's the gem you're using for bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

an easy fix is put a static color value in your file, such as "#778899"

Here are some css color value translations from their variables: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colorsfull.asp